# Count published sticky posts on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to get the number of **published** sticky posts on Wordpress. I can retrieve the number of sticky posts with

```
$sticky = count(get_option('sticky_posts'));
```

but it includes the planned posts, I don't want to include them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to filter these posts.

```
$args = [
        'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),
        'post_status' => 'publish'
];

$posts = new WP_Query($args);

var_dump( $posts->posts );
```

Comment: And then, $sticky_count = $posts->post_count; It works, thanks